# How to connect NativeScript application to SQL database?

Tags: sql, azure-sql-database, nativescript

I just started creating an application using NativeScript using Angular. I created a database using Azure and SQL. I'm really confused on how to connect the two though and can't find too much on it. Could someone help me out? Thanks!

Comment: I would say to consider having an API which can speak to Azure DB and have NativeScript app to call the API if you are considering real-time option. You can also use NativeScript azure mobile apps plugin to connect with DB hosted in Azure Mobile App Service. This plugin do not have offline sync capabilities.

Comment: Look at this Web resource: http://nuvious.com/Blog/2015/3/21/using-nativescript-with-azure-mobile-services

Answer (score 2):

None of the mobile apps connect to SQL database directly, you will expose REST services which will act as a middle man between your mobile app and database.

If you don't have a backend setup, then other option is to try one of the mobile backend services, Firebase for instance.

Comment: Can you provide some tutorials or demos of how to use NativeScript app with Firebase and what modules to use ?

Comment: You will find the demo code and all documentation in the plug-in repo.